Почему после старта сервера могут отсутствовать данные в "Политике безопасности"?
Изучаю разграничение прав доступа. Запустил сервер, и у меня "Политика безопасности" пустая.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Такое может произойти, если сервер еще не завершил полностью старт, и синхронизация нужных данных еще не произошла. Но чаще всего это происходит, когда эта синхронизация отключена с помощью параметра запуска lsfusion.server.lightstart. Процитирую документацию:

Режим "облегченного" запуска (как правило используется при разработке). В этом режиме сервер не выполняет операции синхронизации метаданных, создания форм настройки политики безопасности и т.п., соответственно уменьшается время запуска и объем потребляемой памяти при запуске. В IDE регулируется галочкой в lsFusion server конфигурации (по умолчанию включена).

Проще всего, как и написано в документации, управлять эти параметром в конфигурации запуска: 
